# Install referrer parameter values modified by Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

I used **Google play install referrer** in my android application and used the following parameters and generated **URL** as it was described:

```
utm_source,
utm_medium,
utm_content,
utm_campaign
```

I wrote my own custom receiver and all worked fine for me, while installing my application received broadcast successfully.

I posted the application URL on Facebook and when I received broadcast my parameter values were changed.

For example I sent:

```
utm_source=somesource,
utm_medium=facebook,
utm_content=samplecontent,
utm_campaign=xyzcontent
```

and while receiving every time i am receiving the same following values in parameters

```
utm_source=apps.facebook.com,
utm_content=myAppId,
utm_campaign=fb4a
```

Why Facebook is changing the parameter values :( ? Is there any way to keep values intact?

Comment: Is there page where the referrer link is listed?